# Laravel L5.5 No access to pivot table in "Many to many" relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Unfortunately, I cannot successfully access a DB column in a pivot table. Besides this, the model is working well.

Model Device

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Task', 'xx', 'yy', 'zz')
    ->withPivot('id', 'duedate', 'interval', 'reoccurdate', 'completed', 'state')
    ->withTimestamps();
}
```

Model Task

```
public function devices()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Device', 'xx', 'yy', 'zz')
    ->withPivot('id', 'duedate', 'interval', 'reoccurdate', 'completed', 'state')
    ->withTimestamps();
}
```

I tried with a very simple example but failed:

```
dd(Task::findOrFail(1)->pivot->created_at);
```

Error:

> "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: what is the output of dd(Task::findOrFail(1))

Comment: do you get the task ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only access the pivot data if the model *collection* is the result of a call to the relation method that is aware of that pivot data, meaning you must access `devices` on a `Task` model to find any pivot data:

```
$devicesForTask1 = Task::find(1)->devices;
$devicesForTask1->each(function (Device $device) {

    // Here we can use pivot, since the models were found through a
    // relation method that implements the pivot definition. each
    // model now has its own pivot property:
    Log::info($device->pivot->duedate);
    Log::info($device->pivot->interval);
    // etc...
});
```

This is because of what pivot data represents: additional data that comes with a relationship definition. So `created_at` represents a statement such as:

*`Task` 1 belongs to - among many - Device x since `created_at`*.

Pivot data does not tell you anything about 1 specific model in of itself.

**Problem 1:**

It is an impossible to determine request to do `Task::find(1)->pivot`, since `Task` might have multiple `belongsToMany` relations, and the expression above does not explicitly specify which relation to access.

**Problem 2:**
Imagine that Eloquent models would have a cure for problem 1 by implementing a method called `pivotFor()` that would let you do something like `Task::find(1)->pivotFor('devices')`. Now there is still information missing, because it is not known which of the related `Device` models we are trying to access the pivot data for (`belongsToMany` queries for a `Collection` of *many* models)

To fix problem 2 our hypothetical `pivotFor` method should accept a second argument of type `int`, whose value matches the id of the target `Device`. But that is just theory. Instead you can try to compose the behavior you're looking for from the facilities that eloquent models, relationships and collections already provide (it's possible), and create this implementation on a higher level (a Support class / repository, for example).

[The Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) provides much more information about how all this works, and it's very likely you'll find a solution there.

**in short:** You'll need to determine:

- Which relation you want to use on `Task`
- Which model of the collection of related you want to get back

Since this is a *higher order* operation - the `belongsToMany` simply does not return single models - you should come up with your own implementation for what you try to achieve.

**P.S.**

`Task::find(1)->devices` returns you exactly `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|App\Device[]`.

You tried to access `created_at` on the pivot object. You should add that to the withPivot call, **if that column indeed exists on the pivot table**:

```
public function devices() 
{
    return $this
        ->belongsToMany('App\Device', 'xx', 'yy', 'zz')
        ->withPivot(
            'created_at', // Only if created_at exists on the pivot table!
            'id',
            'duedate',
            'interval',
            'reoccurdate',
            'completed',
            'state'
        )
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

If you actually intended to get the `created_at` value for a `Task` or `Device` you should access that on the respective model instances directly:

```
$task = Task::find(1);

Log::info('Task was created at: ' . $task->created_at);

$task->devices->each(function (Device $device) {
    Log::info(
        'Device '
        . $device->id
        . ' was created at: '
        . $device->created_at
    );
});
```